# Почему пропадает доменная сеть на одном компьютере с 20.00 до 8.00 и пишет "подлинность не проверена"?

Tags: администрирование

Столкнулся с такой проблемой на предприятии. Обратилась сотрудница с проблемой, что компьютер работает хорошо до 20.00, после 20.00 они, якобы, не могут попасть ни в 1С, ни в сетевые папки, да и ввести пароль и зайти на компьютер становится сложнее (ПК грузит минут 5-10).

После того, как я узнал про проблему, так сразу переустановил в АD учетку, ну соответственно повторно подключился к доменной сети и результата нет, после чего прописал статический IP со всеми настройками (IP так же установил другой) и не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В том что в 20:00 в серверной уборщица выдергивает шваброй сетевой кабель из сервера АД. :) ищите что происходит в сети в это время, или кто то уходя домой выключает проходной свич, или подобная дрянь происходит на самих серверах, еще как вариант - кто то наоборот приходит на работу во вторую смену и в сети появляется 2 компа с одним именем что вызывает некоторые конфликты в пределах сети